# Trazer valor da model para TextArea

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Tenho a seguinte página `cshtml`

```
@using SoftluxWebCore.ViewModels.Tabelas
@model SoftluxWebCore.ViewModels.Tabelas.MensagemViewModel
<!-- Link to CSS -->
<link href="~/css/Geral/create.css" rel="stylesheet" />


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

    using (Html.DevExtreme().ValidationGroup())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <div class="divFormulario">

            <textarea cols=60 id="opiniao" rows="10" name="men_mensagem" maxlength="500" wrap="hard" placeholder=""></textarea>

        </div>
        <br />

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sucesso"><i class="far fa-check-circle"></i> Gravar</button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-cancelar" onclick="parent.fecharJanela('CadastroAmbiente')"><i class="far fa-times-circle"></i> Cancelar</button>

    }
}

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial"); }
}
```

Essa é a página `update`, ela possui métodos `get` e `post` na `controller`, quando eu faço o post, ele me envia da maneira correta, envia para `men_mensagem` que defini no atributo `name`, mas quando faço o `get`, o `textarea` vem vazio, como posso fazer para trazer os dados?

Meu método da controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("Mensagem/Update/{Men_codigo}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Update(int? Men_codigo)
    {
        int? Emp_codigo = Services.Token.strEmp_codigo;
        var UrlApi = $"api/Mensagem/find/{Men_codigo},{Emp_codigo}";
        Uri BaseAdress = Services.Token.BaseAdress;
        string strToken = Services.Token.strToken;

        MensagemModel Ambiente;
        MensagemViewModel AmbienteVM = new MensagemViewModel();
        using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            httpClient.BaseAddress = BaseAdress;
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", strToken);
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("Application/Json"));
            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(UrlApi))
            {
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                string resul = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Ambiente = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MensagemModel>(resul);
                AmbienteVM.Men_codigo = Ambiente.Men_codigo;
                AmbienteVM.men_mensagem = Ambiente.men_mensagem;
            }
        }
        return View(AmbienteVM);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente substituir seu:

```
<textarea cols=60 id="opiniao" rows="10" name="men_mensagem" maxlength="500" wrap="hard" placeholder=""></textarea>
```

Por:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.men_mensagem, new { htmlAttributes = new { @style = "text-align: center;", @class = "form-control col-md-12" } })
```

Comment: Deu certo, porém e como faço para definir número de linhas, colunas, número máximo de caracteres e outras coisas ?

Comment: Corrigi a resposta adicionando como colocar os atributos a textarea.